# Is proving that $\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\|T(t)f-f\|=0$ enough to prove uniform convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

For $f=\sin(x)$ I want to prove that $T(t)f$ does not converge uniformly to $f\in\mathbb{R}$ as $t\to 0$. Note that $T(t)$ is the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck semigroup.

Now, I have a theorem which states that for $f\in BUC(X)$, we have that $\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\|T(t)f-f\|_{\infty}=0\iff\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\|f(e^{-t}\cdot)-f\|_{\infty}=0$.

Observe that for $f(x)=\sin(x)$ we have

$$\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\|\sin(e^{-t}x)-\sin(x)\|_{\infty}=\|\sin(x)-\sin(x)\|_{\infty}=0.$$

Therefore $\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\|T(t)f-f\|_{\infty}=0$. However, this isn't the contradiction that I wanted. In order to prove uniform convergence of $T(t)f\to f$ as $t\to 0$ do I also have to prove it for $t\uparrow 0$? But in this case the theorem I used will no longer be applicable.

Comment: $\lim_{t\to 0}\|\sin(xe^{-t}) - \sin(x)\|_\infty$ is not $0$. For any given $t\not= 0$ you can always find $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sin(xe^{-t}) - \sin(x)$ takes on any value in $[-2,2]$.

Comment: @Winther However, $e^{-t}\xrightarrow{t\to 0} 1$, thus $\lim_{t\to 0}\|\sin(xe^{-t})-\sin(x)\|_{\infty}=\|\sin(x)-\sin(x)\|_{\infty}$. However, since we can always find $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\|\sin(x)-\sin(x)\|_{\infty}$ takes on a value in $[-2,2]$ is this sufficient to prove the non-uniform convergence that I desire?

Comment: You cannot move the limit inside the $\infty$-norm. Also $\|\sin(x) - \sin(x)\|_\infty \equiv 0$.

Comment: @Winther Then do we have $\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\|\sin(xe^{-t})-\sin(x)\|_{\infty}=\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|\sin(xe^{-t})-\sin(x)|=2$?

Comment: Yes. I don't know the theorem you are using, but if what you write it correct then all you need to do is to show that the limit is not $0$. This can be done by constructing a sequence $(x_n,t_n)$ with $t_n\to 0$ such that $|\sin(x_ne^{-t_n})-\sin(x_n)|$ does not converge to $0$. Take for example $t_n = \frac{1}{2\pi n}$ and $x_n = 2\pi n$. This works since the limit is by definition the supremum of all such sequences.

Comment: @Winther But surely if I already have that $\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|\sin(xe^{-t})-\sin(x)|=2\ne 0$ then I do not need to construct any such sequences?

Comment: Sure, that was just to save you the work of *proving* that the limit is $2$. Depending on the context stating that it is so might not be rigorous enough. Since you don't need the exact value a simple construction is easier imo, but that is a matter of taste. You should do it the way you think is best.